# Terraform Import not works properly

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-route53

We have some existing records in aws route53, we need to import those using terraform import command. But after successfully completed the command if we are trying to create again same record which is already present on aws route53, Terraform will delete and recreate those resources. So what would be the best practice after doing terraform import. How can we tell terraform to skip already created resource records?

Comment: Can you add your Terraform code and the commands used to import the Route53 records to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform command :

terraform import module.route.aws_route53_record.automation  Z0396681NV0PE58VHJOH_terraform.test.xxx.io_A

Output :

module.route.aws_route53_record.automation: Importing from ID "Z0396681NV0PE58VHJOH_terraform.test.xxx.io_A"...

module.route.aws_route53_record.automation: Import prepared!

Prepared aws_route53_record for import

module.route.aws_route53_record.automation: Refreshing state... [id=Z0396681NV0PE58VHJOH_terraform.test.xxx.io_A]

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in

your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.

Comment: Using code blocks can improve readability

Comment: this doesn't answer the question of why the import is failing.... I hit the same.  Reports success but nothing imported.